# Set a background colour in a CSS class only when that class is in a div with another specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Sorry if the title is complicated, but that pretty much describes it.

Lets say I have two CSS classes: .class1 and .class2. What .class2 does is irrelevant, however, if .class2 is wrapping a div that has .class1, I need it to be a different colour then if it was alone.

For example:

```
<div class='class1'>
  I should have a red background!
</div>

<div class='class1'>
   <div class='class2'>
     I should have a blue background!
   </div>
  I still should have a blue background!
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.class1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.class2 {
  /*Contents are irrelevant*/
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean: *What .class2 does is irrelevant, however, if .class1 is wrapping a div that has .class2, I need it to be a different colour then if it was alone.*

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question linked to. The linked question deals with styling `.div-b` (the child) where `.div-b` is inside `.div-a`. *This* question is about styling `.div-a` (the parent), where `.div-b` is inside `.div-a`.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861 obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.class1{background-color:red}
.class2{background-color:green}
.class1 .class2{background-color:blue}
```

```html
<div class='class1'>
  I still should have a red background!
</div>
<div class='class2'>
     I should have a green background!
</div>
<div class='class1'>
   <div class='class2'>
     I should have a blue background!
   </div>
  I still should have a blue background!
</div>
```

Comment: This answer has two upvotes and yet *I still should have a blue background* has... a red background.

Answer (score -1):

Your css should work:

```
.class1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.class2 > .class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You may check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2p65w7u/3/)

Possibly, there is some syntax errors in your css which causing the following style is ignored by browser, check again your css.